# How to enable caching in ArangoDB via Docker or arangojs?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, arangodb, arangojs

I would like to enable caching in ArangoDB, automatically when my app start.

I'm using `docker-compose` to start the whole thing but apparently there's no simple parameter to enable caching in ArangoDB official image.

According to the [doc](https://hub.docker.com/_/arangodb), all the files in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` are executed at container start. So I added a js file with that code:

```
require('@arangodb/aql/cache').properties({mode: 'on'});
```

It is indeed executed but caching doesn't seem to be enabled (from what I see with `arangosh` within the container).

My app is a JS app using `arangojs`, so if I can do it this way, I'd be happy too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [performance](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.8/aql/execution-and-performance-query-cache.html#global-configuration) and [server config](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/3.8/programs-arangod-query.html#aql-query-results-cache-size) docs, you can enable caching in several ways.

Your method of adding `require("@arangodb/aql/cache").properties({ mode: "on" });` to a `.js` file in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` directory should work, but keep an eye on the logs.  You may need to redirect log output with a [different driver](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#logging-drivers---log-driver) (journals, syslog, etc.) to see what's going on.  Make sure to run the command via `arangosh` to see if it works.

If that's a bust, you might want to see if there is a way to pass parameters at runtime (such as `--query.cache-mode on`). Unfortunately, I don't use Docker Compose, so I can't give you direct advice here, but try something like `-e QUERY.CACHE-MODE=ON`

If there isn't a way to pass params, then you could modify the config file: `/etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf`.

And don't forget about the REST API methods for system management.  You can access AQL configuration (view and alter) in the Web UI by clicking on the `Support` -> `Rest API` -> `AQL`.

One thing to keep in mind - I'm not sure if the caching settings are global or tied to a specific database. View the configuration on multiple databases (including `_system`) to test the settings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What worked for me is to edit `arangod.conf`. Adding `[query] cache-mode = on` made the trick. I added it as a volume in docker-compose to make it persistent: `- ./conf/arangodb/arangod.conf:/etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf`